# Get excel in sharepoint to google drive

Tags: google-drive, sharepoint

Is there any way to import an excel file located in a sharepoint into a google drive site?

Comment: Please describe what Sharepoint is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the Excel file
2. Go to [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/), log in to your Google account, and go to the folder you want to put the Excel file into.
3. Click on the multicoloured + icon on the top left, which says "New", and select  "File upload". Select your Excel file in your file explorer.

If you followed those steps, you now have your Excel file stored in Google Drive (although it is a separate copy from the one in Sharepoint). Further, you can convert it into a Google Sheet by right-clicking, then selecting "Open with" > "Google Sheets". This will create a separate Google Sheet file.